# What is faster/more efficient, read/write to file or to io file like object?

Tags: python, file, io

I am working with some large audio files (~500MB), with a lot of processing and conversion involved. One of the steps involves writing a file, sending it though a network, then reading the file at arrival, then saving the file based on some logic. 
As the network part is irrelevant for me, I wonder what is faster or more efficient, reading and writing actual files, or io file like object.

Also, how significant is the performance difference, if at all.

My intuition would say io object would be more efficient, but I do not know how either process works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`io` file-like object has been created to avoid creating temporary files that you don't want to store, just to be able to pass to other modules and "fool" them into believing that they're actual file handles (there are limitations but for most usages it's okay)

So yes, using a [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) object *will* be faster, even with a SSD drive, reading/writing to RAM wins.

> class io.BytesIO([initial_bytes])
>
> A stream implementation using an in-memory bytes buffer.

Now if the data is very big, you're going to be out of memory or swap mechanism will occur. So there's a limit to the amount of data you can store in memory (I remember that old audio editing software were able to do "direct-to-disk" for that very reason: memory was limited at the time, and it was not possible to store several minutes of audio data in memory)